# How to find problems in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`195414_py82740`@`%` PROCEDURE `getUserMail`(inUserId INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT default 0;
    DECLARE tmpMailId INT default -1;
    DECLARE tmpFromUserId INT default -1;

    DECLARE cursor1 cursor for select id from mail WHERE toUserId=inUserId OR fromUserId=inUserId ORDER BY sentDate desc;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_userMail;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_userMail LIKE mail;

    OPEN cursor1;

    REPEAT

        FETCH cursor1 INTO tmpMailId;

        SET tmpFromUserId = IF ((SELECT fromUserId FROM mail WHERE id=tmpMailId)=inUserId, (SELECT toUserId FROM mail WHERE id=tmpMailId), (SELECT fromUserId FROM mail WHERE id=tmpMailId));

        IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM temp_userMail WHERE fromUserId=tmpFromUserId || toUserId=tmpFromUserId) THEN
            SET tmpMailId = 0;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO temp_userMail
                (`id`,
                `fromUserId`,
                `toUserId`,
                `sentDate`,
                `readDate`,
                `message`,
                `fromUserNickName`,
                `toUserNickName`,
                `subject`,
                `fromUserDeleted`,
                `toUserDeleted`)
            SELECT
                (m1.id,
                m1.fromUserId,
                m1.toUserId,
                m1.sentDate,
                m1.readDate,
                m1.message,
                m1.fromUserNickName,
                m1.toUserNickName,
                m1.subject,
                m1.fromUserDeleted,
                m1.toUserDeleted)
            FROM mail m1
            WHERE m1.id=tmpMailId;

        END IF;

        UNTIL(done = 1)

    END REPEAT;
    CLOSE cursor1;

    SELECT * FROM temp_userMail ORDER BY sentDate DESC;

END
```

The SP is saved successfully but when running it I get the cryptic exception

> Error Code: 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

I know what the error means but there is no line nr so I have no idea where to look for the problem?

Comment: if you print tmpFromUserID after you set it what does it show?

Comment: Im not use to working in the MySQL workbench so how do I do this? Is there a way to debug the SP?

Comment: Apologies, I use Management Studio; I don't know about MySQL workbench either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove brackets from Your SELECT subquery

dont use

```
 SELECT (id, ... m1.toUserDeleted) ...
```

use

```
 SELECT id, ... m1.toUserDeleted ...
```